# Is there any bug with document.write()?

Tags: javascript, onload

I had my code something like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", "");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

And I wanted to write something more, I added a new line.

Like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", "");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

And then, suddenly, my input tag disappeared.

So, I wrote 'AAA'to check whether the `<br>` code was added or not.

Like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", "");
    document.body.appendChild(x);

    document.write("<br>");
    document.write("AAA")
}
```

There's a new line, and AAA.

So, I think there's an bug or something with `document.write()`.

Is there any bug?

Or did I write something wrong?

My purpose is to add a new line.

I want to make my code run properly.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to _Stack Overflow_, um…, so what's the problem? Your `<input>` being overwritten by `document.write()`?

Comment: @K._ No. My problem is that I can't add new line. I want to add new line and write something, but when I write `document.write("<br>")`, the prior code disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, if the page has already loaded, `document.write` will *replace* the *entire* page with the new HTML string. If you removed your `window.onload` handler and simply had that snippet run as soon as the browser comes to the `<script>` tag, both the `<input>` and `<br>` would be inserted into the document as expected:

```html
<script language="javascript">
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "text");
  x.setAttribute("value", "");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  document.write("<br>");
</script>
```

Generally, the solution is to *not* use `document.write` - its behavior can be confusing, and it provides nothing that can't be accomplished just as easily with methods such as `appendChild` and `insertAdjacentHTML`, for example:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

or

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br>');
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Then is there any way to set that when the page is loaded?

Comment: Don't use `document.write` after the page is loaded, because then the page will be replaced - use other methods like `appendChild` and `insertAdjacentHTML` instead, there's no way around it.